# Non-Void Method invoking without assigning return value

Tags: java

I tend to think that most of the time that variable returning methods are invoked to assign the return value to a variable, e.g.:

```
return1 = object.DoSomething();
```

Nevertheless, Apart from executing the method: What happens when a returning method is invoked and the return value is not assigned to a variable? e.g:

```
object.DoSomething();
```

Is this a good practice? Where does the `return` goes?

JB Nizet made a remarkable comment stating that methods are implemented for most cases. Kind of explains why this situation occurs often.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is valid. Unless you have a need to use the return value further down, it is better to ignore (You can save from code review tools flag as un-used variables).

Method execution and flow stays same, only thing is you are ignoring return value.

It is good practice or not depends on situation, for example if you have requirement like how many rows update on executing query, you need to capture return value, but most of the times developers ignore this because they don't need to track how many records were updated.

Answer (score 10):

People do it all the time.  If you don't need the variable that the method returns, than you don't have to assign it to anything.

Bear in mind, that sometimes the return variable has some meaning, like whether or not the operation was successful, and you might want to do something with that information

Comment: Best answer. I would upvote it, but I'm out of votes for the day (I'll try to remember to upvote it later).

Answer (score 1):

The method is invoked in the same fashion as it would when the return value is assigned to a variable.

This is a perfectly acceptable practice, and is a necessity when invoking `void` methods, which do not return values (and therefore cannot be assigned to objects).

Answer (score 1):

**-** Its always better to use `void` as a **return type** where you don't want to assign or use the returned value.

**-** It won't cause any problem in its efficiency but will be considered as loose programming.

Comment: Both your points are invalid if the OP has no control over the method in question.

Comment: The implementor of the method doesn't know if the caller will need the returned value. How many times have you actually used the result of `Collection.remove()` or `Map.put()` for example? It can be a bad practice in some cases (like `InputStream.read()`), and can be perfectly valid in some cases (like ignoring the result when calling a fluent builder).

Comment: @DuncanJones my points are not valid, i have written my 2nd point to explain that this won't do any harm on its efficiency...but then when you don't need a return value of method to be used , then don't return it.

Comment: @KumarVivekMitra: your point is still invalid. Many methods are not written for just one one use-case. And some use-cases might need the returned value whereas others don't need it.

Answer (score 0):

That code will compile and run perfectly normal.

Comment: The question is about good practice. I suspect the OP knows the code compiles.